# Python String with HTML /

Tags: python, html, string, decode

I'm trying a simple program to send some html down a socket to a client. 2 things are goofing me up.

The code:

```
c.send( str.encode("<HTML><BODY>Test Page<///BODY><///HTML>") )
```

My python client receives:

```
b'<HTML><BODY>Test Page<///BODY><///HTML>'
```

According to Beginning Python which says it covers Python 3 (I'm using 3.1.1 on Windows), there is a String.Decode function. My environment cannot find it. I assume I'll run into the errors ('strict', 'ignore', 'replace' ) next.

Obviously, the extra /// is just guessing.

1) How do I decode this in Python?
2) I use my browser and obviously the HTML code is wrong, but I can see the server sent it.  How do I make the HTML browser friendly?

Cordially,

Stephen

Answer (score 1):

You want `'...'.encode()` and `b'...'.decode()`. Saying "str.encode" is shorthand for saying that all str literals have this method.

Comment: >>Saying "str.encode" is shorthand for saying that all str literals >>have this method.

My environment can't find decode.  Not quite sure what what you mean by all str literals have this method.

Comment: I said "encode". You said "decode". Which one would you like to talk about?

Answer (score 0):

The extra '/' is wrong. You only need to worry about escaping for '\'

Comment: @Stephen Deetz: Can you tell the difference between / and \?  One needs escaping and one does not.  Do not escape /.  Ever.  Sometimes you need to escape \ as \\.